# Sequelize is returning integer as string

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I using nodejs v4 with sequelize, and I have a model like this:

```
var Device = sequelize.define('Device', {
id: {
  type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
},
tenantId: {
  type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
  allowNull: false
},
token: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false
}
}, {
 tableName: 'devices'
});
```

When I select a device by id the type of id is a string, exemple:

```
Device.findById(9).then( function(result) {
  console.log(result.toJSON().id + 10);
});
```

The output will be 910, rather than 19, so I look at json and a saw this:

```
{
  id: "9"
  tenantId: "123"
  token: "adsadsdsa"
}
```

The id in found device is a string, but I defined it as a number...

Doesn't it should be { "id": 9 } ?

How can I select a device with the types that I defined previously?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a fix to this problem on sequelize repo.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4523

The pg module used for sequelize returns bigint as string because bigints are not guaranteed to fit into js numbers. So I change my model to use integer (DataTypes.INTEGER)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I think you would have to change your DB schema as well for this to work. In my example (postgres) it doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 11):

BIGINT maximum value is 2^63-1, javascript can safely represent up to 2^53. To be on the safe side libraries return those numbers as strings.

If you want to have numbers instead of strings, you can use this library https://github.com/mirek/node-pg-safe-numbers which deals with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, a smoother solution is to force parsing of int to int, instead of strings. Checkout [this issue and comments](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2383#issuecomment-58006083).

Comment: but what will be the result if the int from the string is larger then the biggest safe int in JS?)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to put this line before your logic code worked for me, this forces parsing of int8 to int, instead of strings:

```js
require("pg").defaults.parseInt8 = true;

...

try {
    const list = await Posts.findAll();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
}
```

Comment: This works for my use case, but worth noting that if you have numbers larger than 2^53 then it may return incorrect values.

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit request to your answer by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

What I did on my sequelize model was to apply `parseFloat` in the `getter` function

Here is a sample typescript code

```
@Column({
    type: DataType.DECIMAL(9, 2),
    get() {
        return parseFloat(this.getDataValue('amount') as string);
    },
})
amount?: number;
```

With this, you can apply your logic to deal with small and big int datatypes

Answer (score -3):

By default, sequelize try format your results. You can set `raw :true` for get raw data