# Testing Node.js API that uses Sequelize with Mocha/Expect/Supertest

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, sequelize.js, expect

I have been working on a nodejs API that works with postgres and I'm having an issue testing with `expect`. Sequelize is returning all fields as a string value no matter what the type is.

When using `.toMatchObject` an error is thrown because in original object and in database `id` is a numeric value, but is returned as a string. Same happens with decimal.

Is there a way to get data how it's stored, not as string?

Is there different way to check if objects match without having to parse each attribute to be same type as original ?

I tried using `raw:true` as i read online, but it didnt work. 
Node version is 9.9, expect version is 22.4.3, sequelize version is 4.37

Testing code that fails is as follows:

```
it('should create new zgrada', (done) => {
    var newZgrada = {
        sifra_zgrade: 1006,
        ulica: "Derpa derpsona",
        kucni_broj: "77",
        dodatak_na_kucni_broj: "A"
    };
    request(app)
        .post('/zgrade')
        .send(newZgrada)
        .expect(200)
        .expect((res) => {
            expect(res.body.zgrada).toMatchObject(newZgrada);
        })
        .end((err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            db.zgrada.findAll({
                where: {
                    sifra_zgrade: newZgrada.sifra_zgrade
                }
            }).then((zgrada) => {
                expect(zgrada.length).toBe(1);
                expect(zgrada).toMatchObject(newZgrada);
                done();
            }).catch((e) => done(e));
        });
});
```

Error received is:

1) POST /zgrada
       should create new zgrada:
     Error: expect(received).toMatchObject(expected)

```
  Object {
    "dodatak_na_kucni_broj": "A",
    "kucni_broj": "77",
-   "sifra_zgrade": 1006,
+   "sifra_zgrade": "1006",
    "ulica": "Derpa derpsona",
  }
```

When I swap `toMatchObject()` with `.toBe()` then it works but I have to go through each attribute separately and cast the ones that are numeric to string first which is not practical for a bigger project with different models and many attributes.

edit: model definition (some attributes are left out but not relevant for error):

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
var Zgrada = sequelize.define('zgrada', {
    sifra_zgrade: {
        type: DataTypes.NUMERIC(0, 4),
        unique: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    ulica: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    postanski_broj: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    kucni_broj: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    dodatak_na_kucni_broj: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
}
```

Post method:

```
router
    .post("/", async (req, res) => {
        try {
            var body = req.body;
            var zgrada = await db.zgrada.create({
                sifra_zgrade: body.sifra_zgrade,
                ulica: body.ulica,
                kucni_broj: body.kucni_broj,
                dodatak_na_kucni_broj: body.dodatak_na_kucni_broj,
            });
            res.send({
                zgrada
            });
        } catch (e) {
            res.status(400).send(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Can you show us some test code that fails with the error?

Comment: I placed code in first post with error that i receive, thank you for help and formating.

Comment: can we see 1) the model definition 2) the POST /zgrade method ? This may not be a sequelize issue at all, and be related to the `pg` module. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544151/sequelize-is-returning-integer-as-string might help

Comment: i updated question with model and post method. it is missing some attributes but they are nor relevant for the error. 
i have googled this problem a lot and i saw this topic that you also linked, but i am not using bigint data type. API will work instead of current program so i have to use existing data which is coded with sifra_zgrade (id) as 4 digit code. 
In database its stored as numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sequelize is returning all fields as a string value no matter what the type is.

Sequelize uses the `pg` module as a bridge for postgres. In `pg`, `Decimal` (alias: `Numeric`) type are returned as `String` values by design for reasons concerned with the safety and precision of `parseInt` in JS. [For more information see this Issue on node-postgres Github](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/811#issuecomment-116644535).

> Is there a way to get data how it's stored, not as string?

As of Sequelize version 4.32.5, an underlying dependency regarding type parsing was changed and there is an [open issue with the same concern as this question linked here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9074).

In short, there isn't much you can do with your current setup.

Other Solutions:

1) Use a different type such as `DataTypes.UUID` or `DataTypes.Integer` if possible. Especially given that `sifra_zgrade` seems to be acting as an primary key/id column, it seems likely that the type could be changed.

2) Rollback to Sequelize version 4.23.3 and manually change how `pg-types` parses decimals **only if you're operating within a safe decimal precision range**:

```
var pg = require('pg');
pg.types.setTypeParser(1700, 'text', parseFloat);
```

> Is there different way to check if objects match without having to parse each attribute to be same type as original ?

As far as I understand, solutions would have to use underlying type-converting comparisons (`==`) instead of strict equality comparisons.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 

I changed the type to `Integer` which works for this attribute, but I have some attributes that represent currency that have the same issue as this and cannot be represented only as `Integer` from obvious reasons. precision range is not an issue because it never has more than two decimal places and total up to 7 digits.
I will try to check the second option you mentioned, hopefully it will work. 

Do you have any info if this will be "reimplemented" in future releases of sequelizemaybe as an option to run with conversion or not?

Comment: I'd subscribe for notifications to that open issue thread I linked. It is very likely a solution will come soon given that in prior versions one could override pg-types. They changed dependencies which was either a mistake or means there will be a new way to parse decimals.